# Sending i18n message as a parameter to a template inside another template

Tags: scala, templates, playframework, internationalization

I would like to give as a parameter, inside a template, i18n message to another template:

In messages.en

```
cases.title = Title
```

In a template:

...
`@text(...,label = @Messages("cases.title"),..`.)
...

In the text.scala.html template:

```
@(..., label: String = "CHANGEME",...)
...
<h1>@label</h1>
```

But apparently this doesn't give expected result. How can I give i18n message as a parameter to a template?

Answer (score 0):

I hope somebody finds it helpful, answer came to me after I posted the question, unfortunately. Turns out this works:

```
@text(...,label = Messages("cases.title"),...)
```